# ¿Cómo guardar el resultado de un store procedure en una variable SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedure

Buenas quiero realizar algo básico, es guardar el resultado de un 'store procedure' en una variable, pero no me permite ejecutarlo. Agradezco su colaboración:

```html
declare @variable int = exec dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada tu procedimiento almacenado debe tener variables OUTPUT, las mismas que serán devueltas y las que puedas asignar a tu variable, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFecha   
        @fecha datetime OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    set @fecha = GETDATE()
END
GO
```

en este sencillo ejemplo, se retorna el valor de la fecha-hora actual en la variable @fecha.
Ahora vamos a hacer un ejemplo de la llamada y asignación en una variable:

```
declare @mifecha datetime;
exec getfecha @mifecha output;
print @mifecha;
```

Resultado = Feb 21 2020  5:47PM

Espero te sirva para solucionar tu problema!.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta

```
declare @variable int 
exec @variable = dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'
```

Puedes intentar algo asi

```
declare @variable int 
exec @variable = dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'

SELECT '31/07/2016' as FECHA, a.dfechaform as FORMALIZACION, a.dfechavenc as VENCIMIENTO CASE WHEN C.CCODMONEDA = '002' THEN A.nsaldocred * @variable ELSE A.nsaldocred END AS SALDO FROM PRUEBAS
```

Comment: Me sale un error  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.

Comment: Edite la respuesta, lo puedes checar porfa

Comment: WHEN C.CCODMONEDA = '002' THEN A.nsaldocred * dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'
       ELSE A.nsaldocred END AS SALDO,

Comment: Me sale error al multiplicarlo en un select sabes el motivo ?

Comment: Un procedimiento puede devolver múltiples conjuntos de resultados, cada uno con su propio esquema. No es adecuado para usar en una instrucción SELECT., debes crear una funcion en su lugar. saludos

Comment: es que el procedimiento almacenado esta bloqueado para convertirlo en una funcion

Comment: Puedes poner  todo el select donde te muestra el error porfa

Comment: SELECT     '31/07/2016' as FECHA,  a.dfechaform as FORMALIZACION, a.dfechavenc as VENCIMIENTO
CASE
WHEN C.CCODMONEDA = '002' 
THEN A.nsaldocred * EXEC dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'
ELSE A.nsaldocred END AS SALDO

FROM PRUEBAS

Comment: estoy tratando de multiplicar la columna del select * el sp con el parametro de fecha para que me devuleva el tipo de cambio .

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, ssaludos